# Pandas first_valid_index, can it be used for finding the first non-zero value? (Tom Starke Vectorised Backtest example)

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to follow this [article](https://aaaquants.com/2017/08/18/quant-basics-2-vectorised-backtest/#page-content) by Tom Starke, to create a vectorized backtester in Python using pandas.

I note that in the narrative he states:

> This is done by finding the first non-zero value, which is either +2
> or -2 and divide it by 2.

Yet the code segment that seems to correspond to this is:

```
for col in actual_signals.columns:
    idx = actual_signals[col].first_valid_index()
```

As far as I can tell from the documentation, first_valid_index() is used to find the first non-NA, non-null value, but this is different to the first non-zero value.

Has anyone else looked at this article and discovered the same issue, or am I missing something? If you can see my misunderstanding, could you point it out to me please?

I find that if I replace the second line with:

```
idx = actual_signals[col].ne(0).idxmax()
```

Then I think I get the desired result, but I'd like to know if I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Yes you are right; using `first_valid_index` is wrong and misleading (even though it *happened* to work for the particular data). Your way is much better but it will give 0 for `idx` when *all* the values in the column are equal to 0. So, to avoid that, one can use `actual_signals[col].where(actual_signals[col].ne(0)).first_valid_index()` which returns `None` if no value is nonzero in the column.

Comment: Thank you, that's super helpful, first to know I'm not misunderstanding, and secondly for the better solution you provided than the one I currently had. Thanks again.

Comment: It think it's confusing me for the next section of the article as well, because when he does the "Testing the Code" section, he gets a signal line with one blip at +1 and one blip at -1. Yet when I do it, using the first non-zero value (instead of first non-NA, non-null value) I get a blip at 0.5 because of the division by 2.

It is because he has generated synthetic data with a price series going from many 0's to many 1's. So the first crossover of SMA of LMA isn't a real crossover, they go from the same to SMA > LMA. Real price data just won't do that (SMA = LMA exactly).

Comment: hi @Wei, I'm afraid I don't follow exactly because I'm not familiar with the technicalities associated with the article (i guess it's related to finance? `:)`) But if you can provide some minimal reproducible example in the question that is decontextualized from the technical aspects (like you had done in the current question above), I (and others) can look at it and may be of help; because I don't know what LMA is, for example (that's my lack of knowledge of course `:)`).

Comment: No need, really thank you, you've been a big help already. The way you related to my post, I actually assumed you have been through the article before and had the same issues yourself. I'm fairly clear now, thanks again for your clarification.